# Another Rook's Tour of the Chessboard

Tags: mathematics, graph-theory, checkerboard, primes

Place numbers 1 to 64 in the cells of this 8 x 8 board in such a way that consecutive numbers occupy neighboring cells (either vertically or horizontally). Shaded cells must be occupied by prime numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the solution I got.....

> [image]

Comment: Interesting. So it seems there are many different solutions

Comment: @DrXorile I wrote a program to check, there appear to be 4 solutions: https://pastebin.com/UeDRbX5J

Comment: Me too. Agreed!

Comment: I think there are 4 solutions with a Hamiltonian path and only one solution with a proper tour (where values 1 and 64 are neighbors).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Show us, please!

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos See https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2021/09/another-rooks-tour-of-chessboard.html for a detailed discussion how I arrived at this conclusion.

Comment: Here is another model that finds all the proper tour solutions (which is one), this one using the MiniZinc constraint modelling language: https://gist.github.com/zayenz/46fb486a4454aac72127376436b823ef

Answer (score 5):

The start has to be:

> [image: step1]
>  There's only a handful of primes that are separated by 2. And, apart from 3-5-7, there's no 3 odd numbers in a row that are prime (well-known result, but easily verified up to 64). So that shows us this:
>  [image: step2]
>  Note the corners have to be connected to the two squares on either side. This means the top-left and bottom-right corners can't be looping back onto the shaded areas (that would be two primes separated by 1). And the bottom left is one of the 5 composites in a row. The lack of 2 primes in a row add a few more restrictions to the path, which I've shown as a red line (i.e. the path can't go through the red lines).
>  Next I took an intuition that the bottom left must surround the 47-53-59 sequence (with 53 on the isolated shaded spot). I tried a few ways to get the end sequence (which needs 59-61-and the final tail of 3 composites), and eventually hit on using up the space on the right (I almost discarded it because it's not unique). But doing this and the rest fell in place:
>  [image: final answers]